# Cannot assign a value of type '[PHAsset]' to type 'UIImageView!'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, phasset

> Cannot assign value of '[PHAsset]' to type 'UIImageView!'

I'm having an issue here:

[image]

**UPDATED QUESTION**

```
    // CONVERT PHASSET TO UIIMAGE
func getAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
    let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var image = UIImage()
    option.synchronous = true
    manager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        image = result!
    })
    return image
}




func doneButtonDidPress(images: [UIImage]) {



    self.imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    var selectedImg = imagePickerController.stack.assets

    getAsset(selectedImg)
    self.SelectImageView.image = UIImage(named: chosenImg)



    }
```

But yet i get errors as shown in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable *selectedImage* is of type **PHAsset**

The variables *self.backgroundImageView* and *self.SelectImageView* are of type **UIImageView**

These two types do not match, so Swift will not allow you to make the assignments.

To make the assignment, you will have to **convert PHAsset to UIImage** and then assign this **UIImage to the UIImageView**

Comment: @MartinQ I have answered that in the last part. There are multiple answers on StackOverflow on how to do these conventions

Comment: Ok, i've been at this for a while and i'm a bit stuck. Do i convert it outside of the button function? or do i convert it in the button function. When i convert outside the button function, then call the function in the button, it says: cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'PHAsset'

Answer (score 0):

`[PHAsset]` is an array of `PHAsset` objects.  To get an image from the array, get the `PHAsset` from the specific index you want and use [`requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:) to get the image from the asset.

Comment: using my code above, could you give me a rough layout of how to do that? ... Im feeling slightly lost. Thanks

Comment: JAL, is there anyway you can express it in code? I understand your instructions but i'm stuck on this and i have no help. If you don't bind, i would be really grateful of your help. Thanks